# Genymotion and Amazon Register

Tags: android, genymotion

Can anyone with Genymotion installed please download and check if the Amazon Register app will run.

It gives an error about the device being modified/jailbroken and won't start in BlueStacks.

Please let me know if the app runs in Genymotion. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.localregister.android&hl=en

Anyone know any alternatives that can run the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payment apps like Amazon Register and Android Pay will not run on rooted or modified devices for obvious security reasons. Both BlueStacks and Genymotion fall into this category.

Just to be sure, and since you asked, I tried to install Register into a Genymotion VM running the "Google Nexus 5 - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 1080x1920" image with Google Play Services installed. Installation is fine, but running it gives the same result you describe for BlueStacks. FWIW, my rooted HTC One (M7) running AICP 10 does the same thing as well.

To overcome this, you might try something like [Xposed RootCloak](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-rootcloak-completely-hide-root-t2574647). There are folks reporting that they got Register working using this, but I didn't in my brief experimentation.

UPDATE: I can personally attest to the fact that Amazon Register will run on a RootCloaked device (HTC mentioned above). When I get a chance, I will try the same in a Genymotion VM.

Comment: Well I know Paypal Here, also a payment app, works on Bluestacks. I use it for my business because my employees have an easier time and make less errors on the computer than a mobile device.

Comment: They are all a little different in their requirements, for sure.  Please accept and/or upvote answer if my time spent investigating for you helped at all.  Thank you.